# U-Substitution Inconsistencies with multiple methods

Tags: integration

> Use the substitution $u = e^x$ to evaluate the following integral.
>
> $$\int \frac{e^x}{1-e^x} dx$$

Here's what I did:

$$u = e^x$$

$$\therefore \frac{du}{dx} = e^x$$

$$\therefore dx = \frac{1}{e^x}du = \frac{1}{u}du$$

$$\therefore \int \frac{e^x}{1-e^x} dx = \int \frac{u}{1-u} \frac{1}{u}du$$

$$= \int (1-u)^{-1} du$$

$$=\ln(|1-u|)$$

$$=\ln(|1-e^x|) + c$$

However, evaluating the original integral online gave me $$\int \frac{e^x}{1-e^x} dx = -e^x-\ln \left(\left|e^x-1\right|\right)$$

Plotting both my result and the result directly above, the two curves were not vertical translations of one another - is there an incorrect step in my working out?

Comment: You missed a sign; your procedure would lead to $-\ln(|1-e^x|) + c$. What you got online does not seem to be correct (at least, to me).

Answer (score 1):

The integral should be: $-ln(\vert1-e^x\vert)$.

Remember the chain rule: the derivative of $ln(1-u)$ is not $\frac{1}{1-u}$, but rather $\frac{-1}{1-u}$. But our integral is $\int \frac{1}{1-u} du$, so we need to divide $ln(|1-u|)$ by the derivative of $1-u$, $-1$, to correct for the chain rule in order to have the correct integral.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to confirm would be to differentiate both of them-however, let us assume that you did not have the result.

Your steps are absolutely correct, except in the last bit.

Note that in the last line, if $1-u=t$, then $du=-dt$.

Thus, we get $$\int (1-u)^{-1} du =-\int t^{-1} dt = -\ln (|t|)+C =-\ln (|1-u|)+C=-\ln(|1-e^x|)+C$$

Where $C$ is a constant.

The answer they gave you online was wrong.

Indeed, [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex%2F(1-e%5Ex)) shows your steps were right.

However, it **would** be correct if the question was

> Use the substitution $u = e^x$ to evaluate the following integral.
>
> $$\int \frac{e^{2x}}{1-e^x} dx$$

Indeed, note $$\int \frac{e^{2x}}{1-e^x}dx=\int -e^x+\frac{e^x}{1-e^x}dx=-\int e^x dx+\int \frac{e^x}{1-e^x} dx=-e^x-\ln(|1-e^x|)+C$$

Comment: Oops, I forgot the C!

Answer (score 1):

To know which is correct, simply differentiate:  $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \log (1-e^x) \right] = \frac{1}{1-e^x} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}[1-e^x] = \frac{-e^x}{1-e^x}.$$  So, in fact, there should have been a negative sign.  However, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[-e^x - \log (1-e^x)\right] = \frac{d}{dx} [-e^x] + \frac{e^x}{1-e^x} = -e^x + \frac{e^x}{1-e^x} = \frac{e^{2x}}{1-e^x}$$ is clearly not the original integrand.